# calculate possible traffic light combinations (using if A then !B)

Tags: problem-solving, boolean-algebra

I need to calculate all possible traffic lights combinations possible on two crossroads. I have made a list that shows what traffic lights can NOT be green if a certain traffic light is green.

Example list: (should ouput: A&E, B&D)

```
A --> !B !D
B --> !A !E
D --> !A !E
E --> !B !D
```

> What method can i use to calculate all possible combinations from this
>   list?

*Note: I have about 10.000 possible combinations combinations*

Comment: what's happened to C?

Comment: What about no traffic light being green, is that also a solution? Or only A?

Comment: Its just an example, the names are not really relevant.

Comment: @ peter If A and E can be on at the same time, its not usefull to leave A on alone. Although I dont mind if none or only A would be the outcome aswell.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you cannot prevent a huge number of valid solutions. This is illustrated well in the following example:
$$
A_1 \implies !B_1 \qquad B_1 \implies !C_1 \qquad C_1 \implies !A_1 \\
A_2 \implies !B_2 \qquad B_2 \implies !C_2 \qquad C_2 \implies !A_2 \\
\dots \\
A_n \implies !B_n \qquad B_n \implies !C_n \qquad C_n \implies !A_n
$$

Here, we have $3n$ traffic lights that form "triangles": For each $i$, only one of $A_i,B_i,C_i$ can be green. This gives you a choice of 3 options for each triangle, resulting in a total of $3^n$ possible solutions. If we also consider "non-maximal" solutions (i.e. some traffic lights are unnecessarily off), you have $4^n$ possible solutions.

Thus, there is no efficient algorithm that can solve your problem, simply because there are potentially way too many solutions. I would approach the problem heuristically: Start with saying that $A$ is green, then recursively check which solutions result from that. Then, check that happens if $A$ is red.

Comment: I don't mind having a big list of solutions and if I have a method I can code a solution that does the math for me. I think it should be something like get a list of all combinations and then substract the combinations that don't work with the rules I set up (like if A then (!B, !C)). I don't fully get what you mean with An, since I only have one traficlight with id A

Comment: I just used slightly different names than you do in order to make my example more understandable. Instead of names $A,B,C, \dots$, I use names $A_1, A_2, \dots, B_1, B_2, \dots$.

Comment: Generating all combinations first and filtering out the invalid ones is certainly an option (this is not the fastest way, but since any way is slow, this might not be an issue for you). Usually, one creates such lists of combinations by recursion: Start off with an empty list and recursively append both options "red" and "green" to the list.

Comment: I think ill try that method, It's the only way i know i can programm, thanks for the advise